# Microsoft Powerapps - How to connect to different datasource in one form

Tags: sharepoint, office365, powerapps

I'm building an app for TravelInfo. Here are the fields: From, To, City, Country.

I am using common data source entity. And for the country lookup, I want to use a sharepoint list, that has all the country names.

I'm stuck at this stage. As you see in the snap, I want to connect the country dropdown to a sharepoint list.

[I've tried to achieve the same with picklist. But Its not good to manually create the huge list of countries in picklist. Sharepoint list should be ideal.]

[image]

Here is the question: In one form, how can I use different datasource for different fields??? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form will save the data card value defined in `Update` into the field defined by `DataField`.  You are trying to change data displayed on the dropdown which is not set in the Fields list you have above.  Try the following (the first few steps may already be completed based on picture):

1. Check `Country` to insert data card into form
2. Select data card and under Advanced properties click `Unlock to change properties`
3. Delete text box from data card that was added by default
4. Select data card and insert desired control (drop down box)
5. Select drop down box (not data card) and under Advanced properties define `Items` and `Value` to populate values from the sharepoint list
6. Select data card and change `Update` to desired dropdown value that should be saved e.g. `dropDown1.Selected.country_id`

The drop down box can display the Country text on the form, but then save an associated value such as the country id.